# Baking emission in Cycles makes line artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking, artifacts

I started texturing my model and I noticed that all the procedural textures I made by plugging them into Emission and backing it using "Emit" have weird lines and dots. These artifacts do not happen if I bake with 1 sample.

For example, here is my node setup:

[image: Node setup]

This gives me this result:
[image: Procedural result]

However, when I bake the texture I get this:
[image: Baked result]
[image: Baked result highlighted]
[image: Baked result in texture editor]

These are my baking settings

[image: Bake settings]

The UVs are correct, there is no overlap.

I tried changing the margin, swapping Viewer by proper Emission, copying the object to the new file and baking there, nothing helped.

Any ideas what is causing this and how it can be fixed?

Edit:
I tried baking the same material on default cylinder in new file, the same artifact occurs. Baking a default material with "Combined" settings does not produce the lines, so it is something to do with emission.

Tried on different versions (2.82a, 2.83.3 and 2.83.5) they give the same result.

I found a way of baking masks without the artifacts, if I plug it in roughness input of a shader (like Principled BSDF) and bake with "Roughness" setting, it gives a correct result.

Comment: maybe it's an artifact caused by the format (png), and instead of baking you should render an image in OpenEXR format?

Comment: The lines are still visible with OpenEXR. They show in texture view in Blender, so I guess no matter the format, they will be there.
I added some new information to my original post, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to reduce or shorten quads/tris.

I looked into blender bug reports with another blender user and found one similar to this, where in the comment section it says that long tris can be an issue with the cycles render engine - https://developer.blender.org/T81710

Alternatively you can increase the resolution of the bake, and then downscale in an attempt to mask/hide it

Hope this helps, as this issue I imagine is common, and not well documented