# Baking Artifacts - Lines dots or dashes

Tags: baking, error, artifacts

Just wondering if anyone knows how to solve these lines/dots that are appearing on my bakes. They also appear on other bakes such as diffuse bakes too.

If you want anymore details that you think are important, such as settings, then I can add those in.

The top image shows the lines I'm refering too when baking AO on a model. And the bottom image shows some of the dots when baking diffuse. I'm certain both are both have the same cause.

[image: Baking AO Artifact]
[image: Baking Diffuse Artifacts]

I also see that other people have had the same issue:
[Baking emission in Cycles makes line artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191876/baking-emission-in-cycles-makes-line-artifacts/245015?noredirect=1#comment417257_245015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is having too long tris/quads (so shorten them using loops, the knife tool, etc.)

Apparently the blender/cycles engine does not like this according to a comment on a previous bug report - https://developer.blender.org/T81710